# Is there a way to convert an image in the FLIR proprietary .seq format into .png?

Tags: c++, png, file-conversion, flir

I'm trying to convert a frame in `.SEQ` format into `.PNG`

I used the pleora `ebus-sdk` to automatically find and connect to my gigE FLIR camera.

Then I used:

```
PvBuffer* data = (PvBuffer*)myFLIR.GetFrameData();

void* data1 = myFLIR.PrepareTauSEQ(data);
size_t size = sizeof(FFF_FILE_HEADER) + sizeof(BI_DATA_T) + sizeof(GEOMETRIC_INFO_T) + data->GetAcquiredSize();
```

If I write `data1` with `size` to a .seq file using `std::ofstream`, I can then open this .seq file in any FLIR software with no problem.

But, I want to have a PNG instead of a SEQ. How should I do this?

Comment: Try asking Pleora if they have any tools to save images in any conventional format then use **ImageMagick** to convert any one of 200+ formats to PNG. Add a note here if they have such a tool for there folks to find.

Comment: You should be working with the FLIR ATLAS SDK: https://www.flir.com/products/flir-atlas-sdk-for-.net/

It's based on Pleora of course but has a lot of great functionality.